# How to get multiple values from input field in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to get input field values which are in foreach loop using jquery .  Here is the html structure

```
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <div class = "form-row"> 
           <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"value="{{$product->quantity }}">
           <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price"value="{{$product->price}}">
         </div>
    @endforeach
```

I'm trying to get value in this way

```
     var quantity = $('.quantity').val();
     var price= $('.price').val();
```

But In this way, I get only first-row value. How can get all rows value using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through all the elements to get the values from them.

You can try jQuery's [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get all the values in an array.

**Demo:**

```js
var quantityArr = $('.quantity').map(function(){
  return +this.value;
}).get();
console.log(quantityArr);
// if you want the value comma separated then join the array
var quantityCommaSeperatedString = quantityArr.join(',');
console.log(quantityCommaSeperatedString);

var priceArr = $('.price').map(function(){
  return +this.value;
}).get();
console.log(priceArr);
// if you want the value comma separated then join the array
var priceCommaSeperatedString = priceArr.join(',');
console.log(priceCommaSeperatedString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"value="1">
<input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price"value="10">

<input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"value="2">
<input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price"value="20">

<input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"value="3">
<input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price"value="30">
```

Update: As mentioned in the comment: get values by row

```js
$('.form-row').click(function(){
  var quantity = $(this).find('.quantity').val();
  console.log(quantity);
  var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
  console.log(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "form-row">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"value="1">
  <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price"value="10">
</div>

<div class = "form-row">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"value="2">
  <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price"value="20">
</div>

<div class = "form-row">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"value="3">
  <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control price"value="30">
</div>
```

Comment: What if I only I want to get specific rows quantity, Suppose, I click on 2nd row then I'll get 2nd row quantity value , If I click on 5th row then I will get only 5th row quantity value. How to do that?

Comment: @ihprince, I can't see any row in the HTML. Please update the HTML for that scenario...

Comment: Updated the HTML . If $products have 10 products then the div will be shown in 10 rows.

Comment: @ihprince, added another anoswer, please check:)